# Access and send GPS coordinates in a secondary thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-contentresolver, android-context

My goal is to send the GPS coordinates of my mobile phone to a Java application on my computer, via wifi.
I can already send the SMS or the contacts, so the connection is working well, only the GPS part seems to be an issue.

Here is the code :

```
public class AccesGPS extends Activity {

private LocationManager locationManager;

public AccesGPS(){

    locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

public ArrayList getPosition(){

    Location position = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    ArrayList resultat=new ArrayList();
    resultat.add("Coordonnées GPS : " + position.getLatitude() + " , " + position.getLongitude());
    return resultat;
    }

}
```

and the main Service :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID){

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(MainActivity.IPutilisee),2015);
                ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                        AccesGPS accesGPS = new AccesGPS();
                        output.writeObject(accesGPS.getPosition());

        }
    };

    t.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

}
```

(I only left the relevant code)

I get the errors :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
        at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:735)
        at com.example.maxime.servicesms2.AccesGPS.<init>(AccesGPS.java:15)
        at com.example.maxime.servicesms2.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:88)
```

Line 15 is :

```
public AccesGPS(){
```

and line 88 is :

```
 AccesGPS accesGPS = new AccesGPS();
```

Why am I getting these errors, and how can I solve them simply ?

Answer (score 0):

try this this may help you

```
 Thread t = new Thread(){

    public void run(){


Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

  Looper.loop();

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(MainActivity.IPutilisee),2015);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    AccesGPS accesGPS = new AccesGPS();
                    output.writeObject(accesGPS.getPosition());

    }
};

t.start();
```